# i tried to make c program where user need to input the name and email and system will print out their name on it

Tags: c, char, character

```
#include <stdio.h>

void header();
void movieShow();

int main()
{
    char name;
    char emel;
    printf("\nplease log in first \n");
    printf("name :");
    scanf("%s", &name);
    printf("email :");
    scanf("%s", &emel);
    printf("\nLOG IN SUCCESFUL!!\n");
    printf("welcome %c, what movie you want to book?", name);
}
```

The output I get is not properly what I want.

```
please log in first 
name :ad
email :123

LOG IN SUCCESFUL!!
welcome a, what movie you want to book?
*** stack smashing detected ***: terminated
```

It seems at last print statement it say that `%c` is not properly used for char data...

Comment: You're overflowing your memory, which is super dangerous.  `char` only holds a single character.  You need an array of char to read your string into.  It must be at least big enough to hold any string you will read _and_ a string terminator byte.  It's safer to use `fgets`, where you can guarantee someone won't enter a string that's longer than your available buffer.  When you output that array, use `%s` also, not `%c`.

Comment: Please study the string handling beginner FAQ here: [Common string handling pitfalls in C programming](https://software.codidact.com/posts/284849). FAQ 1) and 2) in particular.